# How to create ODBC DSN for AccredoSuturn or what is the ODBC connection string for Accredo?

Tags: odbc, powerbi, dsn

not sure how to fill the DSN config fields for Accredo, or how to write the ODBC connection string, please help.

The DSN or ODBC connection string will be used in Power BI to get data.

The .PDB files I believe are data files, and I guess when the DSN or ODBC Connection String works, SQL Statement like 'SELECT * FROM INHEAD' from invoice header table should work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might reach out to [Accredo themselves](https://accredo.co.nz/), who provide this ODBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

Got answer from Accredo, as below

Data Source Name: the name to use for the data source

Description: a description for the data source

System: the path to Accredo, for example, E:\AccredoSaturn

Company(database): the name of the folder containing the Company data files, under E:\AccredoSaturn\Data, it's also equal to the Company code

User Name: Accredo user name

Password: the password for the above user

[image]

Also the login user needs the database access permission:

[image]